# UTF-8 encoding in NSIS version info

Tags: nsis

I have this simple UTF-8 script

```
Unicode true

VIProductVersion "0.0.0.1"
VIAddVersionKey "ProductName" "Test"
VIAddVersionKey "FileVersion" "0.0.0.1"
VIAddVersionKey "FileDescription" "Test installer"
VIAddVersionKey "LegalCopyright" "Me © 2022"

Section
SectionEnd
```

The issue is with the © character. After compilation with NSIS 3.08, the copyright info ends up in the installer resources as `Me \xC2\xA9 2022`

[image]

It seems that the source is transformed into UTF-16 byte by byte, rather than character by character. Is there a way how I can ensure proper UTF-16 encoding of that character? I can probably always use (c) instead, but I'm wondering if there's some other way (except using UTF-16 for the whole script)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Unicode true` specifies that you want to generate a Unicode installer but it does not change the interpretation of the .nsi file itself (however, it will change the default of !included files).

If the MakeNSIS output includes a line that looks like `Processing script file: "C:\Users\Anders\test.nsi" (ACP)` then that means the compiler is using the default codepage for ANSI programs when it is parsing your .nsi (for compatibility with NSIS v2).

There are several ways to fix this:

- Manually specify the Unicode character codepoint: `"Me ${U+A9} 2022"`.
- Make sure your .nsi file has a BOM so it is parsed as UTF-8.
- Compile as `MakeNSIS /INPUTCHARSET UTF8 MyFile.nsi`